# PHP fsockopen 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, fsockopen

I have this strange problem that I'm receiving 400 Bad request as a response and I have absolutely no idea what's wrong with the header. Here's my code:

```
<?php

$sock = fsockopen('IP ADDRESS', 80, $errno, $errstr);

$header = array(
    'GET / HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: stackoverflow.com',
    'User-agent: My Useragent',
    'Connection: Close'
);

fputs($sock, join('\r\n', $header));

while(!feof($sock))
{
    echo fgets($sock, 128);
    break;
}

fclose($sock);

?>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**: Thanks to MrCode this problem was solved. Issue was here:

```
fputs($sock, join('\r\n', $header));
```

I had to change it to:

```
fputs($sock, join("\r\n", $header)."\r\n\r\n");
```

**Notice double quotes and "\r\n\r\n"**

Thanks again to MrCode

Comment: I had a similar problem where I was joining the headers with \n. That worked when connecting to older servers but started failing with newer servers. I guess \r\n is the standard and the newer servers were stricter about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `\r\n\r\n` which is required after the final header. Currently you have nothing after the final header.

Append it to the join result:

```
fputs($sock, join("\r\n", $header) . "\r\n\r\n");
```

Also, you need to use double quotes around the `\r\n` because using single quotes causes PHP to take it literally and not as a new line.

Comment: I tried it before too and I tried it now, but it still gives 400 error. http://pastebin.com/MspRazgG and a screenshot: http://puu.sh/feOE7/f86c88f098.png

Comment: Use double quotes not single.

Comment: Well, that's awkward.. it worked now, thank you very much. I didn't know that this kind of things matter.